# Call method will null this object

Tags: javascript

I can call a method like this

```
Func.apply(null,[123]);
```

If the function relies on the `this` pointer, will it throw an exception?

Comment: try yourself. if it throws then ask here why?

Comment: Different implementations may vary

Comment: That depends on what the function is doing with `this` and whether the function is in strict mode or not. It might or might not throw an error. It would definitely throw an error in strict mode though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Mozilla Development Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

> #### thisArg
>
> The value of `this` provided for the call to `fun`. Note that this may not be the actual value seen by the method: if the method is a function in non-strict mode code, `null` and `undefined` will be replaced with the global object, and primitive values will be boxed.

In other words, unless the function uses strict mode, then `window` will be used instead of `null`. If it does use strict mode, `this` will be `null`.

Whether that causes any exception depends entirely on the function being applied. If the function does not use `this`, it is perfectly safe to pass any value at all. If it treats `this` as a plain object that may not be null, it is likely to fail in strict mode only. If it relies on some property being set, chances are it will throw a `TypeError` in strict mode and non-strict mode alike. It is quite easy to create a function that fails in non-strict mode only as well (by adding explicit checks, for example)

(at least some) built-in array functions use an explicit check. For example `Array.prototype.split(undefined, [1,2,3])` on Chrome throws a `TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined`